# How to replace a word (search_string) with the value of an array where the key is the search_string

Tags: php, arrays, csv, replace

I dont find the correct way to replace a word in a string where the word_to_be_replaced is a key and the word_to_replace_with is the corresponding value from a csv.

Example:

```
String: "The water is blue."
csv:
sky, ocean
colour, mood
water, painting

Expected outcome:
"The painting is blue."
```

I´m a beginner in php. I've asked a somewhat similar question - but I can´t make the answer I received work...

So far I´ve got:

```
$file = fopen("mods/test.csv","r");
while (($csv = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
    $replace[$csv[0]] = $csv[1];
}
$blub = strtr($mpref, $replace);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `print_r($mpref); print_r($replace);`

Comment: you should explode $csv to get array

Comment: That code works just fine for me

Comment: I would check your CSV File.

Comment: All I would do is add a `trim()` around both `$csv[0]` and `$csv[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `str_replace`. Check the [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

You need to build 2 arrays, `$search` and `$replace` which will contain the values to be searched and replaced respectively.

```
$file = fopen("mods/test.csv","r");
$search = array();
$replace = array();
while (($csv = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
    //$replace[$csv[0]] = $csv[1];
    $search = $csv[0];
    $replace = $csv[1];

}

$mpref = "The water is blue";


echo str_replace($search, $replace, $mpref);
//prints The painting is blue
```

Comment: Thats how I would have done it, but its not how the question say s the OP wants to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$file = fopen("mods/test.csv","r");
$search = array();
$replace = array();
while (($csv = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
    $search = $csv[0];
    $replace = $csv[1];

}

$mpref = "The water is blue";

echo str_replace($search, $replace, $mpref);
```

In above it will create an array of `words to be replaced` i.e. `$search` and array of `world to be replaced with` i.e. `$replace`. And str_replace consider arrays and replace a word in `$search` with the word in `$replace` having the same key index in both the arrays.
For more info check this [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Which unfortunately means it also ignores the basic request which is _where the word_to_be_replaced is a key and the word_to_replace_with is the corresponding value_